# PHP not showing sessions firefox

Tags: php, firefox

I am currently using sessions to my site for authentication. The site is working fine. But I am not sure why it is not displaying any of the sessions in the developer options. I am currently using firefox. I went to developer options and went to storage options in it. Then I went to the cookies option. There is only one cookie set it is PHPSESSID. It is constant for all users. Doesn't sessions appear there ?? I am not sure about this. Can anyone guide me thanks!

**UPDATE:**

After every login I am setting sessions like

```
$_SESSION['user'] = md5(rand(1000,100000).$row['user_id']);
```

but the developer options display this everytime. (I checked on single browser).
[image]

Comment: Sessions are stored on the server not in the browser. That cookie correlates to the session information stored on the server.

Comment: So, Is there no problem with my current user login ?? the session is getting updated everytime and to every user. But the cookie remains same. Is there any security risk with it ?

Comment: Try to print_r($_SESSION); and check if sessions created exists or not... secondly see for url when you are redirecting users are in same format or not.. e.g. with www. to without www. or vice a versa... this simple www. to non www. mistake took my two hours to find issue..

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by constant for all users but a session is associated with a browser not a user. The contents of what you store in a session is what you would relate to a specific user. If you use a different browser does the cookie value change (betting it does)?

Comment: @DrJManish different users are having different sessions. I checked it. And details of the user also are being returned accordingly.

Comment: @Dave I shall update the question

Answer (score 0):

Actually Sessions are stored in server not in your browser. There is a only key called PHPSESSID as a cookie. It's encrypted. If you want to see all the session data, You can try this code,

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

OR

```
print_f($_SESSION);
```

If you want to make session accessible from all of your domain, You need to set the `session cookie` domain to wildcart. Because If you create session from your site `www.mysite.com` You can't access that session in your other sub domain like `account.mysite.com` So to do that you need to configure in `php.ini` OR execute `ini_set("session.cookie_domain","*.yoursite.com");` in php script.